Inkscape - Using Union for multiple objects
I am trying to use Union to attach 2 graphics to a circle.  One is working but the second one is not.  Is it possible to use this technique for multiple objects or is there another way to accomplish this?  Thanks for your help!

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please show some screenshots of what you are trying to acheive, or what is failing? Multiple objects can usually be united using a Union boolean operation.  So, it's hard to tell what's up. How are the objects constructed? Are any of them in groups?  Please edit your question and add more info, Thanks.
